# Autolayout error in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7

Tags: ios8, autolayout

Im getting this error but only in iOS 8 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint must contain a first layout item'`

When the exception happens the problem is the code doesnt break on the line itself. The code is breaking on the creation of a button, well any UIButton for that matter. I even commented out the button the code was breaking and it just crashed on the next button being created. I read online this error is caused by one of the parameters being nil but i cant seem to find it because the line of code it is breaking on is never displayed.

Comment: Can you provide us your code + where exactly ( in which method ) are you instatiating your buttons?

Comment: Sorry i actually figured this out a little while ago. What happend is i declared one of my UIbutton properties the datatype of assign. So when it hit the constraint function the button was nil. Whats weird is that in iOS7 this didnt cause an issue but in iOS8 it did.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i actually figured this out a little while ago. What happend is i declared one of my UIbutton properties the datatype of assign. So when it hit the constraint function the button was nil. Whats weird is that in iOS7 this didnt cause an issue but in iOS8 it did.